# Создать bash скрипт который группирует файлы и ищет последний

Tags: linux, bash, резервное-копирование

Суть задачи.
Нужно создать bash скрипт, который в папке с бэкапами, будет находить последний бэкап для каждого `FileName` и оставлять его, остальные удалять.
За удалением вопрос не стоит, но проблема создать файл с исключениями.
Есть набор бэкапов в формате:

```
FileName1_backup_2021_07_08_020002_8911811.7z
FileName1_backup_2021_07_09_020002_1962478.7z
FileName1_backup_2021_07_10_020001_3497985.7z
FileName2_backup_2021_07_08_020002_8755507.7z
FileName2_backup_2021_07_09_020002_1962478.7z
FileName2_backup_2021_07_10_020001_3497985.7z
FileName3_backup_2021_07_08_020002_8911811.7z
FileName3_backup_2021_07_09_020002_1962478.7z
FileName3_backup_2021_07_10_020001_3497985.7z
FileName4_backup_2021_07_08_020002_8911811.7z
FileName4_backup_2021_07_09_020002_2118806.7z
FileName4_backup_2021_07_10_020001_3497985.7z
FileName5_backup_2021_07_08_020002_7661758.7z
```

С условием, что мы не знаем какое будет название для файла `FileName`, но точно знаем что оно будет повторяться.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться или `find` с его удалялкой согласно маске или всё-таки перейти на что-то `borg`\ `rdiff-backup`-подобное, потому что там это встроенная фича.

Comment: Настроить `logrotate` и не выделываться? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поиск самых свежих бэкапов

```
ls *_backup_*.7z | \
    sed -e 's/_backup_[0-9_]\+\.7z//' | \
    sort | uniq | \
    while read fname; do 
        ls "${fname}"_backup_*.7z | tail -1
    done
```

`sed` отрезает хвосты именам файлов, `sort|uniq` создаёт список префиксов, в цикле для каждого префикса формируется список файлов, из которого извлекается последний.

Результат на вашем списке

```
FileName1_backup_2021_07_10_020001_3497985.7z
FileName2_backup_2021_07_10_020001_3497985.7z
FileName3_backup_2021_07_10_020001_3497985.7z
FileName4_backup_2021_07_10_020001_3497985.7z
FileName5_backup_2021_07_08_020002_7661758.7z
```

Comment: Спасибо, Работает!